# User interaction with Crystal reports through Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I am creating a crystal report using visual studio 2008 that loads up company records from the sql database.

I want to be able to insert a user interaction prompt so that when someone is using the report they have to choose which company they want to look at by entering the company id.

Is there a way to do this?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways that I can think of (and probably more that i've forgotten :)

1. - Create a report with company_id as a parameter
   - Load the report passing the user entered parameter
2. - Create a report without a parameter
   - Load the report passing and expression using the user entered parameter as selection criteria

If you need any pointers at how to do either of these please let us know which language you are using and we can provide some links/samples.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am doing it all through visual studio so it is based on SQL.

Comment: i meant which programming language :) vb.net or c#?

Comment: ha! sorry, i was having a dumb & dumber moment then!  VB.NET